# Experiment with C programming - Waste RAM with malloc() function

Tags: c, malloc, heap-memory

I just started learning C and I want to make some experiments to get used to important elements of the language, like pointers, memory management and so.

I was wondering if I can make a program that wastes 1 GB of your RAM. Like when you execute the program, you can actually see in your Task Manager how magically 1GB of RAM is being used.

The code I think could be used would be:

```
int * wasteOneGigOfRAM()
{
    int *p = (int *)malloc((sizeof(int) * 256) * 1024 * 1024);
    return p;
}
```

That function returns the pointer so that memory can be free later with another function, something like

```
int * waste = wasteOneGigOfRAM();
//Have fun seeing the task manager
// ...
free(waste);
```

The functions will be called via menu, so I can fill the RAM and then with a menu item I can free it.

But the first function won't fill one gig of RAM. How can I actually achieve it?

Comment: You are allocating 1024 bytes only.

Comment: @ForguesR Makes sense!, let me change my code and see if it changs anything

Comment: It should be 1024*1024*1024.

Comment: @ForguesR I changed it to: int *p = (int *)malloc((sizeof(int) * 256) * 1024 * 1024); But still not seeing it wasting RAM, what do you think?

Comment: I think you're on Linux and refused to read how virtual memory works on it.

Comment: @Blindy I'm on Windows

Comment: Are you filling the memory with values are simply allocating? Also, should simply be: `int *p = malloc((sizeof(int) * 256) * 1024 * 1024);` (no cast to (`int*`)

Comment: @IwillnotexistIdonotexist Thank youk, I will read it! The title of that question wouldn't come up on google with the terms I was trying to use!

Comment: @JuanBonnett No problems! Keep your question here though; The topic of why `malloc()` doesn't give you memory until you actually use it is one that everyone conceptualizes differently, and so your question can serve as a [signpost to the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates).